# Convert left outer join to where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to simplify this confusing left outer join statement into something easier to read by possibly using a where-statement

```
Select approved.orderId
From  (select distinct orderId from OrderLine where isApproved = 1 and isDismissed = 0) approved
      left outer join 
      (select distinct orderId from OrderLine where isApproved = 0 and isDismissed = 0) unapproved 
      on approved.orderId = unapproved.orderId
Where unapproved.orderId Is Null
```

To something like:

```
Select orderId
From  (select distinct orderId from OrderLine where (isApproved = 1 and isDismissed = 0) OR (isApproved = 0 and isDismissed = 0 and orderId is null))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.orderId
FROM OrderLine O
WHERE O.isDismissed = 0
AND O.isApproved = 1
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM OrderLine
                WHERE isApproved = 0
                AND isDismissed = 0
                AND orderId = O.OrderId)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the join is trying to get orders that have at least one approved line but no unapproved lines.  That should equate to

```
select distinct orderId 
from OrderLine
where isApproved = 1 
  and isDismissed = 0
  AND orderID NOT IN 
      (select orderId 
       from OrderLine 
       where isApproved = 0 
         and isDismissed = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`except` should work pretty fast for your usecase, and remove the need for both joins and inner queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT orderId
FROM   orderline
WHERE  isApproved = 1 and isDismissed = 0
EXCEPT
SELECT orderId
FROM   orderline
WHERE  isApproved = 0 and isDismissed = 0
```